# C++ 11 string token search

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying to find a token(delimiter) in a string and then value in between of it.

```
const std::string s("str1;str2;str3");
```

here i want to find value str1 str2 and str3. trying to use 
std::regex but what will be regex value? tried

```
std::regex words_regex("(\\*;)");
```

but not working

Comment: If you are trying to split with `;`, the regex will be just `;`. What is the rest of your code?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/